# Sequelize how to format sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') in a query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've been trying to compare a date (`yyyy-mm-dd`) to `sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` as shown below:

```
dataagendado: {
    [Op.gte]: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
}
```

This works for **greater than** cases but **not** when the value of `dataagendado` is **equal** to today's date. I believe I need to format the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` data. I've been trying to find an answer but all I get are formatting for when a column is created, which doesn't seem to be applicable inside a SELECT query. I've also tried `sequelize.fn('NOW')` and formatting it but got no luck.

Am I even on the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Postgres as the underlying database?

Comment: No, sorry, I wasn't able to verify that yesterday with certainty. I'm using MySql but your answer provided insight enough for me to figure the rest of it out myself, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm assuming you are using Postgres as the underlying database. If it's not the case, please post your database engine.

You are using `sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` which resolves in Postgres to `NOW()`. The `NOW()` function returns the timestamp with the current time. If you are comparing your date without the timestamp against a date with a timestamp that shouldn't work.

You could use something like this:

```
dataagendado: {
    [Op.gte]: sequelize.literal('now()::Date')
}
```

In SQL the following happens:

`SELECT NOW()` => `2021-03-31T07:39:24.518Z`

`SELECT NOW()::Date` => `2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: I'm using MySql as the database, thanks to your comment I realized I misunderstood what the sequelize.literal does, I was looking for solutions via sequelize when I should be looking for a database function. Using `[Op.lte]: sequelize.literal('CURDATE()')` worked for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to staaar's answer I got enough insight to realize that I should be looking for a function in the database's documentation and not in Sequelize's documentation or threads. I'm using MySql as the database so the current date function I should be using looks like this:

```
    dataagendado: {
        [Op.lte]: sequelize.literal('CURDATE()')
    }
```

[Here's the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), maybe look for something similar in your database's documentation. Best of luck!

Thanks again to user staaar!